# Touch-manipulation is freezing my udp-sending in Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango)

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-phone-7, udp, windows-phone-7.1

I have a weird problem with the Windows Phone 7.1 API. Im trying to write an app to send touch-delta from the touch-screen to move a mouse-pointer on a desktop-pc. Im using UDP-sockets but I have some performance-issues.

The sending of udp-messages seem to freeze for 0.5-1.0 sec every ~0.5 seconds or so. Im not sending huge amounts of data and Im throttling it as well. My latest attempt to find whats causing it turned out a bit unexpected.

When having a separate thread with a while-loop that keeps sending random-data everything works smooth and fine. But when I start touching the screen of the WP7-mobile I start getting these weird hiccups. I have removed all listeners on touch-events for debugging purposes and Im not doing anything else in my app then sending this data on a UDP-socket. But why is it freezing up like this when I move my finger over the screen? It kind of makes it impossible to write an app like this.

I've heard that touch-manipulation should be moved to a dedicated thread, is that included in the Beta2 refresh of WP7.1?

The code goes somewhat like this:

```
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _event.Reset();
            _socket.SendToAsync(_args);
            _event.WaitOne();
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }).Start();
```

The event-handle is set when SendToAsync is completed. So it keeps sending udp-data about every 5 ms. It works fine (I can receive in a steady and rapid rate) as long as I dont touch and drag my finger on the phone's screen. Then I start getting 1 sec freezings in regular intervals. Very strange since Im running the udp-firing on a separate thread. Is the CPU of the phone being overloaded in some way when its processing manipulation? Could that be causing the hiccups?

---

**Update**

I've refrased and updated this question in another thread to make it a bit more clear:

[Poor UDP performance with Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930977/poor-performance-of-udp-on-samsung-omnia-7-with-windows-phone-7-1-mango)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Poor performance of UDP on Samsung Omnia 7 with Windows Phone 7.1 (Mango)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930977/poor-performance-of-udp-on-samsung-omnia-7-with-windows-phone-7-1-mango)

Answer (score 1):

Everything runs on the UI thread till you push it to another thread. Most of my event handlers look like this

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => /* do stuff */);
```

I have Mango b2 and it is true that some stuff has been moved off the UI thread but this is erratic and it's easy to do it yourself.

Comment: The weirdest thing is that Im allready running my udp-firing on a separate thread. Its just a while-loop that keeps sending random data. Its going about just fine until I start touching the screen. Its really strange.